# Issues with regex for apache to exclude certain things

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a regex for apache 2.4 and what I am attempting to make work is that I have a HTTP_HOST and REQUEST_URI that I am attempting to get to rewrite as I expect.

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).(?:dev|staging|prod).(?:domain1|domain2).com$
RewriteCond  %1##%{REQUEST_URI} (.+)##\/([^\/]+)
RewriteCond  -f "/upload/%1/assets/%2/%2.html"
RewriteRule ([^\/]+) "/upload/%1/assets/$1/$1.html" [R]
```

I am able to match the items that I would expect. So if I would make a request to subdomain.dev.domain1.com/verntest, it does successfully rewrite, but it also attempts to rewrite the rewritten elements

So.
`/upload/subdomain/assets/verntest/verntest.html` works
and then
it gets rewritten to `/upload/subdomain/assets/upload/upload.html`

I would like to get this so that it doesn't match the second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to use regex anchors to restrict your pattern:

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).(?:dev|staging|prod).(?:domain1|domain2).com$
RewriteCond  %1##%{REQUEST_URI} (.+)##/([^/]+)
RewriteCond  -f /upload/%1/assets/%2/%2.html
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /upload/%1/assets/$1/$1.html [L,R]
```

This pattern will match `/verntest` but not `/upload/subdomain/assets/verntest/verntest.html`